# Como criar um JOB no ORACLE para backup?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados, oracle11g

Boa tarde galera!

Sou novato ainda no assunto quando se trata de sql, gostaria de saber como criar um JOB (Ou outra operação que faça o mesmo) que realize uma extração de dados de uma tabela para um arquivo .sql em um diretório que eu setar.

Se for possível, ele deve fazer isso automaticamente todos os dias em um intervalo de tempo que eu determinar.

OBS: Meu BD é local e esta na versão Oracle 11g Express

É possível?

Desde já eu agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim como fazer um backup, você pode fazer um DUMP do seu banco. Na pasta de instalação do oracle server  tem uma pasta chamada "bin" onde tem vários executáveis e vamos utilizar o "expdp".

Crie um arquivo para execução de comando em lotes (.bat) e dentro dele utilize a seguinte linha de comando:

expdp usuario/senha@banco tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log

Você pode ver mais detalhes em:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Com o .bat criado na mesma pasta do executável "expdp" você vai gerar um arquivo .dump com os dados do seu banco.

Informação importante: na linha de comando tem um parâmetro chamado "directory" e esse parâmetro não é onde você coloca a url da pasta para onde quer que o arquivo (DUMP) do seu backup seja armazenado. Ele é um "alias" como se fosse um apelido para o local de fato.
Esse "alias" está fazendo referência à um caminho real na tabela: DBA_DIRECTORIES

Você pode ver mais detalhes em:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1050.htm#i1576965

Legal, o comando está configurado e o arquivo indo para a pasta que você deseja. Agora para você automatizar isso fazendo com que o DUMP seja feito todos os dias em um determinado horário, você pode criar uma tarefa agendada no Windows, mas não esqueça de deixar habilitado para executar a tarefa com direitos de administrador se não não funciona.

Espero ter ajudado!

Até mais!

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo! Ajudou muito!